# While submitting app in App Store, how to provide credentials when its Mobile OTP based login?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, mac-app-store

Currently, I'm trying to upload an app to the App Store but since my application is OTP-based login, even if I provide my number it'll send the OTP to my number. I'm also using JWT tokens for every logged-in user. Internally every API call is using JWT Auth, So demo creds will be too much of a workaround

I've sent the test credentials as my number and some random OTP and also I provided the details in the notes section but my app got rejected mentioning credentials are not valid. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Normally you would configure your back end so that the demo account had a fixed OTP value or the demo account doesn't validate the OTP and you provide the username, password and OTP to Apple

Comment: In my experience, it is enough to add a note that a demo account will be automatically created once the correct OTP is entered. The AppStore review team has the ability to specify a phone number and receive SMS messages (I once got a rejection due to OTP message not arriving)